# How does subprocess.Popen differ between Windows and Mac OS?

Tags: python, macos, subprocess

I've been running some python code on Windows which opens up another python program 'main_plot.py' using the following line...

```
subprocess.Popen(['C:\\python26\\python.exe ','main_plot.py','-n', str(number_of_cores),'-m', str(number_of_motors)])
```

I've tried to ssh into a Mac OS pc to run the same code but it doesn't work because I think I need to change the path. This was my first guess...

```
subprocess.Popen(['python','main_plot.py','-n', str(number_of_cores),'-m', str(number_of_motors)])
```

but I get the error...
    python: can't open file 'main_plot.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

I've also tried

```
subprocess.Popen(['python','~/code/stochastic/main_plot.py','-n', str(number_of_cores),'-m', str(number_of_motors)])
```

but I get the same error.

I've checked that the file is in '~/code/stochastic' and it is. I'm a bit stuck as what to do next

Comment: Have you tried expanding the path fully? `Popen` doesn't expand shell shortcuts like `~` unless you use `shell=True` (in which case the shell parses the command and handles those).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't a difference between Windows and Mac; it's that you're only using `~` on Mac, and you can't use `~` in a pathname.

Put a different way, `~/code/stochastic/main_plot.py` is not a real pathname—or, rather, it is, but it's looking for a directory named `~` under the current directory, not your home directory. The shell turns that into the real pathname using tilde-expansion. Python can do tilde-expansion as well, but you have to ask it to do so explicitly.

So, the solution is simple:

```
subprocess.Popen(['python',
                  os.path.expanduser('~/code/stochastic/main_plot.py'),
                  '-n', str(number_of_cores),'-m', str(number_of_motors)])
```

As Jeremy Roman points out in a comment, you *can* use `~` in paths if you use `shell=True`, because then Python will put all of your args together into a command line to pass to the shell, and the shell *does* handle `~`. But you don't want to do that. Just call `expanduser`.

For future reference, the same thing is true for all the other kinds of expansion the shell does. You can't do `"${HOME}/foo"`, but you can do `os.path.expandvars("${HOME}/foo")`. You can't do `"foo$((1+1))bar"`; you have to do something like `"foo%sbar" % (1+1,)`. And so on.

Comment: Hi!! I'm sorry for comment in an older post, but I think you really can help me. Could you have a look to this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55197121/subprocess-popen-failing-in-macos-high-sierra-10-13-6?noredirect=1#comment97138917_55197121 . Thanks you very much in advance!