# subprocess.Popen failing in macOs High Sierra 10.13.6

Tags: python, macos, latex

Good morning.

I'm using the following code to generate pdf documents with LaTeX.

```
cmd  = ['pdflatex','-interaction','nonstopmode', name + '.tex']
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
proc.communicate()
```

Variable name is, obviously, the name of a file previously written, and I have perfectly checked that the file exists and it's valid. However, using this code in macOs High Sierra 10.13.6 gives me the following error in the second line (`proc = ...`):

```
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

On the other hand, the code works perfectly in Ubuntu 16.04.

Many thanks you in advance!

Comment: Your word that `name + '.tex'` exists isn't enough to diagnose whatever problem you are having. What's the value of `name`? What is the current working directory of the process?

Comment: name has a value of the form "Revenue profile. From 2018-10-3 to 2018-10-10". I didn't know that I should give a working directory due to I've never used it in Ubuntu and works fine.

Comment: What happens if you add `assert os.path.exists(name + '.tex')` before you run `subprocess`?

Comment: Without knowing how you actually run the code, it's impossible for us to tell if your current working directory is the directory that actually contains the file in question.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: I know that is difficult help with this info, but I can't provide real data, however, I can explain it better: I've an script (name it as `test.py`) that import a library named `compila_latex` (that is stored in another folder named DB_files) using `import sys
sys.path.append('../DB_files') from compila_latex import compila_latex`. test.py is the script that writes the tex file IN THE SAME FOLDER OF test.py, and ´compila_latex` is the function that tries to compile that tex file, but fails. I've tried the `assert`solution but there is no problem.

Comment: The current working directory isn't necessarily the directory where `test.py` is; it's the directory where you actually *run* `python`. If you are doing something like `python /some/other/directory/test.py` from your home directory, then your current working directory is your home directory, not `/some/other/directory`.

Comment: "I've tried the `assert` solution but there is no problem". So no `AssertionError` was raised? Perhaps `name + '.tex'` isn't the file mentioned in your exception, then.

Comment: Sorry, forgot add that I'm running `python test.py`, and, answering your second comment `name + '.tex'`is the same file. I also tried to check it using `os.listdir(os.curdir)`and the file is there... As I said, that all works perfectly on Ubuntu, but not in Mac, so I thought that the problem lies in something that I unaware about MacOs...

Comment: Are you sure you have `pdflatex` installed on your Mac? You'll get the same `OSError` for a nonexistent command.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure, in fact I can compile my tex file from TexWorks with pdflatex without a problem.

Comment: Is `pdflatex` in a directory in your `PATH`?

Comment: Yes...I'm adding it doing `import sys
sys.path.append('/Applications/MiKTeX Console.app/Contents/bin/')`

Comment: `sys.path` is Python's module search path, not your system's executable search path.

Comment: Mm ok, then how I should modify my code?

Comment: You should probably just hard-code the path to `pdflatex` directly in the call to `Popen`.

Comment: Finally, the problem was pdflatex is instaled in a folder different to typical /usr or /bin, so just hard-code the path as you said. Thanks you very much!